# AndroidPlot: Unable to show line chart from List data in Android app

Tags: android, mysql, json, list, androidplot

I want to show some float temperature values against timestamp in an AndroidPlot line-chart and I am retrieving several sets of these values from MySQL database via JSON parsing. The temperature values are being received just fine, and I am trying to save them in a List but when I plot the values, nothing shows up in the GUI on device.

Here are some details of the program: I am using AsyncTask to retrieve temp values in the method `doInBackground()`, and put the code which draws the graph in `onPostExecute()`. I am retrieving 5 values from the database but strangely enough when I put them in a List and try to plot the graph against some 5 constant values like `Number[] seriesNumbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` I get an error in LogCat that the `xVal` and `yVal` parameters must be of same size. I have printed out what I am getting from JSON parser and sure enough there are only 5 values. I think it should at least work when I plot `arraylist1` against itself, but the graph is blank in this case.

My full activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static XYPlot plot;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    static List<Number> arraylist1 = new ArrayList<Number>();

    private static String url_sensor_data = "http://iotautomationtech.com/android_connect/get_sensor_data.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_deviceS = "devices";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_VAL = "value";
    private static final String TAG_TIME = "timestamp";

    Number[] seriesNumbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONArray devices = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_xy_plot_example);

        plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);

        new LoadSensorData().execute();

        plotDraw();

    }

    class LoadSensorData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading sensor data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_sensor_data, "GET",
                    params);

            Log.d("Sensor data: ", json.toString());

            try {

                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

                    devices = json.getJSONArray(TAG_deviceS);

                    for (int i = 0; i < devices.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = devices.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String value1 = c.getString(TAG_VAL); // <-- temperature value from JSON parser
                        String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);

                        value1.trim(); // <-- trim the string

                        if (isFloat(value1)) {
                            float tempVal = Float.parseFloat(value1);
                            arraylist1.add(tempVal); // <-- add it to arraylist1 if it is valid float
                        }

                        Log.d("Check: ", value1.toString()); // <-- returns 5 values in LogCat
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }

    public static boolean isFloat(String number) {
        try {
            return (!new Float(number).isNaN());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void plotDraw() {

        plot.setDomainLabel("Time");
        plot.setRangeLabel("Temp");
        plot.setTitle("Temperature Trend");

        XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(arraylist1, arraylist1, "Series1");

        LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter();
        series1Format.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter());
        series1Format.configure(getApplicationContext(),
                R.xml.line_point_formatter_with_plf1);

        plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

        plot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);
        plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelOrientation(-45);
    }
}
```

The program is working fine with the default test function, and the line-chart shows up:

```
XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(seriesNumbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series1");
```

And it doesn't crash either when I do this, but there is no line, just blank chart GUI:

```
        XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(arraylist1, arraylist1, "Series1");
```

What am I doing wrong here? How could I traverse arraylist1 to see if the values of temperature are actually being saved in the List? Does the SimpleXYSeries() even accept the parameters that I am sending here in the first place?

Any help here is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your background thread is behaving as expected, the most likely problem is that you never redraw the plot when data is added.  Try adding this after **arraylist1.add(tempVal)** in your doInBackground(...) method:

```
plot.redraw();
```